# iOS: Expand cells when clicked on it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell with a label and a button if I click the button the height of the cell should increase and an image should get visible.

I set up autolayout with a height constraint for the image that I change, when the button is clicked.

The constraint that I use on init is displayed correctly (e.g. if I set the constant to 0 or 200). But if I change the constant in the button action, nothing happens.

Here is the logic for the constraint

```
 func toggleImageHeight(){

        cellIsExpanded = !cellIsExpanded

        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.cellIsExpanded ? 200 : 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not proper. please try this.

```
self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.cellIsExpanded ? 200 : 0
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
     self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

this will work.

Comment: it doesn't. Sorry - my code was like yours before I tried different options. Only the value (self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant) in awakeFromNib() is reflected. Later changes not.

Comment: I didn't understand what actually want to says. Do you want to do change your constraints after click on cell ?

Comment: And where you change "self.cellIsExpanded" Boolean variable ?

Comment: sorry another inconsistency in my Stackoverflow code: imagine tableViewHeightConstraint is imageHeightConstraint

Comment: You need to set height and estimateHeight for cell in tableview.
Set UITableViewAutomaticDimension in both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158760/discussion-between-jacky-and-netshark1000).